Django cloned project does not give tables after migrating
I cloned a project that I want to modify and experiment with, and I have all the necessary credentials. However, I'm encountering issues while following the steps outlined in the ReadMe.md file since I cloned it:

Clone the project.

Create a .env file and add the following information:

Database variables:

DATABASE_NAME: Database name

DATABASE_USER: Database user

DATABASE_PASSWORD: Database password

DATABASE_HOST: Database host

DATABASE_PORT: Database port



Authentication variables for the Telnyx API:

Telnyx_v2_key: Telnyx API v2 key

x-api-token: Telnyx API v1 token

x-api-user: Telnyx API v2 user email





Create a virtual environment: python -m venv ./venv

Activate the environment: source venv_telnyx-invoicing/bin/activate.csh

Install requirements: pip install -r requirements.txt

Create a logs directory: mkdir logs

Make migrations: python manage.py makemigrations

Migrate: python manage.py migrate


I’m currently stuck at the migration step. When I try to run python manage.py makemigrations, I receive the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DominykasPavlijus\Desktop\Telnyx-Invoicing-1\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "Project_tenant" does not exist
LINE 1: ...nant"."id", "Project_tenant"."billing_group" FROM "Project_t...

My settings.py file appears to be configured correctly:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DATABASE_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DATABASE_PORT'),
    }
}

This is the model that is causing the issue:
from django.db import models
from cgi import print_exception
from enum import unique
from unicodedata import name

    class Tenant(models.Model):
        billing_group = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.billing_group)

I tried looking at the guides, but nothing seemed correct, makemigrations isn't creating tables in my database, let me know if I am missing something on a first time clone, maybe a step or something?
There are no migration files or folders in this project and this is what my project folder looks like:

The only way it works without errors the migrations I mean is if I get the backup of the production and upload it to my pgadmin....
UPDATE:
I don't know but could this be what is giving the error?:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('', include('Project.urls')),
    path('', include('users.urls')),
    path('', include('callrates.urls')),
    # path('', include('phoneNumbers.urls')),
    # path('', include('reports.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

If I uncomment the parts that are commented out now I get the error, if they are commented out then migrations run, not all, but run....

Are you able to provide a link to the repo or the README.md file?  Also, what postgresql version do you have installed?

@raphael, this is the full ReadMe.md file that I have gave previously

UPDATE:
After going through all the guides and gathering information, I found that the only way it worked without any errors was by following these steps:
Step by step of what I have done:

In git bash I have filled in these commands so that all pf the folders would have a migrations folder with init.py file in them:
mkdir -p callrates/migrations && touch callrates/migrations/init.py`
mkdir -p phoneNumbers/migrations && touch phoneNumbers/migrations/init.py
mkdir -p Project/migrations && touch Project/migrations/init.py
mkdir -p reports/migrations && touch reports/migrations/init.py
mkdir -p users/migrations && touch users/migrations/init.py



2. Then I made migrations by skipping checks, which finally gave me the tables.
python manage.py makemigrations --skip-checks
python manage.py migrate --skip-checks


3. After that I made a —fake migration
python manage.py migrate --fake


4. And after that just to make sure I did migrations like this:
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

I realize that the tables were initially empty, which probably wasn’t the ideal solution, but it worked for me. Later, I imported data into each table, and now everything is working as expected.

try with this tuto :)
Prerequisites
py command should point to python3
py -V
3.10.0
postgresql 16+ must be up and running on your machine with pg_ctl status (Windows), or pgrep -l postgres (Mac), or sudo systemctl status postgresql (Linux)
Git
Create a new folder
mkdir your project && cd your project
Add .gitignore and start git
Add the following .gitignore
.venv
*.sqlite3
pycache
Add your folder to your git
git init
git add . && git commit -m "first commit"
Create virtual environment for Python and activate it
py -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
Install django and pg driver
py -m pip install django psycopg2-binary
Build django skeleton
Below, "core" means the core of our app, "." means build skeleton inside the current folder :
django-admin startproject core .
git add . && git commit -m "django first files"
Change settings.py
Inside settings.py, add localhost to the list of allowed hosts, like this :
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
And database settings like this :

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'webplus',
        'USER': 'webplususer',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


I don't think it will fix the issue, this guide you gave me is not for dealing with the not found relation or am I wrong?
